# Backbone.js firing Collection change event multiple times

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

In one of by Backbone.js views I am updating the attribute "read" of the current model (instance of Message) by using `this.model.set( { read: true } );`. I verified that this command is only executed once (I know about "ghost events"). As you can see below I configured the Collection to fire an update event in which the whole Collection gets saved into a variable.
Unfortunately the `saveToVar` function gets called 3 times instead of one! Also, the first time `saveToVar` is called, `this` correctly consists of all the collection's models, whilst the 2nd and 3rd time `this` only has one model, namely the one I did the update on.
I tracked everything down piece by piece but I have no clue why this happens.

```
window.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

window.MessageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: Message,

initialize: function()
{
    this.on("change", this.saveToVar);
},

saveToVar: function(e)
{
    App.Data.Messages = this.toJSON();
    return;
}

});
```

Comment: I pasted the code into jsfiddle.net, but for some reason I cannot run it? Never used it before, actually. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hvXbn/3/)

Comment: I also dug a bit deeper and it seems that `saveToVar: function(model) { App.Data.Messages = model.collection.toJSON();}` is a work around. maybe `this` in the collection is referring to the model?

Comment: but here again, the event gets fired 3 times!

Comment: You need to include `backbone.js`, `underscore.js`, and `jquery.js` on jsfiddle.net, not just `underscore.js`. Have a look at the *Manage Resources* panel on the fiddle in my answer and you'll see how to include whatever external JS and CSS resources you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your jsfiddle, you're doing this:

```
App.Collections.message = new MessageCollection([ ... ]);
var elements = App.Collections.message.where({ id: 4 });
var item = new MessageCollection(elements);
```

Your [`where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) call will return models that are in the `message` collection, not copies of those models but exactly the same model objects that are in `message`. Now you have two references to your `id: 4` model:

1. The original one buried inside `App.Collections.message`.
2. The one in `elements[0]`.

Both of those references are pointing at the same object. Then you add `elements` to another `MessageCollection`. Now you have something like this:

```
App.Collections.message.models[3]    item.models[0]
                               |                 |
                               +--> [{id: 4}] <--+
```

Both of those collections will be notified about change events on the `id: 4` model since [collections listen to all events on their members](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection):

> Any event that is triggered on a model in a collection will also be triggered on the collection directly, for convenience.

And your collection listens for `"change"` events in itself:

```
initialize: function()
{
    this.on("change", this.saveToVar);
}
```

So when you do this:

```
this.model.set({ read: true });
```

in your view, both collections will be notified since that model happens to be in both collections.

If we alter your event handler to look like this:

```
saveToVar: function() {
    console.log(_(this.models).pluck('cid'));
}
```

then you'll see that the same `cid` (a unique identifier that Backbone generates) appears in both collections. You can also attach a random number to each collection and see what you get in `saveToVar`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mJvJJ/1/

You probably shouldn't have one model in two collections. You probably shouldn't have two copies of the same model kicking around either so cloning `elements[0]` before creating `item` might not be a good idea either. You might need to reconsider your architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can see that .where() is copying the models, whilst .get() is actually only a reference. Is there a way to use .where() to only get a reference on a subset of models within the collection?

Comment: @hofimax: You can get an array but not another collection.